# Restriction of flat morphism to preimage of open subscheme.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, flatness

Let $f:Y \rightarrow X $ be a flat morphism of locally ringed space, i.e. the canonical map $f^\#:\mathcal{O}_{X,f(p)}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Y,p}$ is a flat ring map for every $p \in Y$.

Then we can consider for $U \subset X$ open the map of locally ringed spaces $f_{|f^{-1}(U)}:f^{-1}(U) \rightarrow U$. I thought that the restriction will also be flat as we have for every $p \in f^{-1}(U)$ the identities 
$\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1} (U),p}\cong \mathcal{O}_{Y,p}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{U,f(p)}\cong \mathcal{O}_{X,f(p)}$. Hence $f_{|f^{-1}(U)}^\#:\mathcal{O}_{U,f(p)}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{f^{-1} (U),p}$ is flat as $f^\#:\mathcal{O}_{X,f(p)}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Y,p}$ is flat for every $p \in f^{-1}(U)$.

But then I found this discussion [Restriction of flat morphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162453/restriction-of-flat-morphism) and got confused. So what is the mistake in the argumentation above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is correct in your argument. In fact flat morphisms of schemes are stable under **base** change.

In the linked question the OP restricted also **the domain** of a flat morphism to a closed subscheme and this makes it completely different from the situation you are considering.